# QSqlDatabase: SIGSEV initialization error

Tags: c++, c++11, sqlite, qt5

I am getting a `SIGSEV` error from the compiler but I am not sure why. I am trying to save example data on a `QTableView`. To do that I created a small set of parameters and in the class `dataInfo` I created a `initDataBase(const QString &nameDB)` function for initialization of the database. As I run the small .ui, the compiler fails at `QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");`. Also to cross off one of the option, I added on the .pro file the `QT += core gui sql` statement as standard procedure but still no luck.

The process I am following is:

**1) Setting the Parameters as below:**

**imageparam.h**

```
#ifndef IMAGEPARAM_H
#define IMAGEPARAM_H
#include <QString>
typedef struct Param
{
    int mId;
    QString mPath1;
    QString mPath2;
    QByteArray mImage1;
    QByteArray mImage2;
} Param;
class ImageParam
{
public:
    ImageParam(Param newdata);
    ImageParam(int id, const QString &path1, QString &path2,
               const QByteArray &image1, const QByteArray &image2);
    int id() const { return data.mId; }
    QString path1() const { return data.mPath1; }
    QString path2() const { return data.mPath2; }
    QByteArray image1() { return data.mImage1; }
    QByteArray image2() { return data.mImage1; }
private:
    Param data;
};
```

**imageparam.cpp**

```
#include "imageparam.h"
ImageParam::ImageParam(Param newdata)
{
    data = newdata;
}
ImageParam::ImageParam(int id, const QString &path1, QString &path2,
                       const QByteArray &image1, const QByteArray &image2)
{
    data.mId = id;
    data.mPath1 = path1;
    data.mPath2 = path2;
    data.mImage1 = image1;
    data.mImage2 = image2;
}
```

**2) Setting the `QSQLITE` database**

**datainfo.h**

```
#ifndef DATAINFO_H
#define DATAINFO_H
#include <QObject>
#include <QtSql/QSqlDatabase>
#include "imageparam.h"
class dataInfo : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit dataInfo(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    QString getError() const { return mError; }
    bool initDataBase(const QString &nameDB);
    bool confDataBase();
    bool addItem(ImageParam* imageItem);
    bool updateItem(int idItem, ImageParam* imageItem);
    QSqlDatabase getDatabase();
private:
    QString mError;
    QSqlDatabase mDBImages;

};

#endif // DATAINFO_H
```

**datainfo.cpp**

```
#include "datainfo.h"
#include <QtSql/QSqlQuery>
#include <QtSql/QSqlError>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QVariant>
#define CREATE_TABLE \
    " CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS imageTable" \
    " (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL" \
    " path1 TEXT NOT NULL" \
    " path2 TEXT NOT NULL" \
    " imageA BLOB NOT NULL" \
    " imageB BLOB NOT NULL)"

dataInfo::dataInfo(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{}

bool dataInfo::initDataBase(const QString &nameDB)
{
    mDBImages = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE"); // <-- ERROR HERE
    mDBImages.setDatabaseName(nameDB);
    bool ok = mDBImages.open();
    if(!ok) {
        mError = mDBImages.lastError().text();
        qDebug() << mError;
    }
    return ok;
}
```

**3) on mainwindow.cpp** I am instantiating as below:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "datainfo.h"

    MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
        QMainWindow(parent),
        ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
    {
        ui->setupUi(this);

        // temporary folder
        temporaryFolder = "/home/to/Desktop/folder/tmp.db";
        QFile dbRem(temporaryFolder);
        dbRem.remove();
        mNewDatabaseImages->initDataBase(temporaryFolder); // <-- ERROR HERE
        mNewDatabaseImages->confDataBase();
        mNewTableImages = new QSqlTableModel(this, mNewDatabaseImages->getDatabase());
        mNewTableImages->setTable("imageTable");
        mNewTableImages->select();
        ui->bookMarkTableView->setModel(mNewTableImages);
        ui->bookMarkTableView->showColumn(true);
    }
```

Any idea of what I am missing in this snipped of code? 
Thank for shedding light on this.

Comment: "I am getting a SIGSEV error from the compiler" - Naah. A segmentation fault is something that happens at run-time, *after* the compiler has built your code an you then *run* it. What does your debugger tell you? What does a stack trace of the crash look like? What are the values of relevant variables when you crash? What did you expect them to be?   In short; debug the problem.

Comment: Hi Jesper Juhl, the debugger nerver seems to pass through `mDBImages = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");` which is the initialization function of the database present in the `dataInfo` class. There seems to be a `default connection` error see [here](https://i.imgur.com/Vs8Ayjh.png) if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ Emanuele, I think you are missing some syntax on `SQL` try to switch this on you **datainfo.cpp**

```
#include "datainfo.h"
#define CREATE_TABLE \
    " CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS yourTable" \
    " (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL" \
    " path1 TEXT NOT NULL" \
    " path2 TEXT NOT NULL" \
    " imageA BLOB NOT NULL" \
    " imageB BLOB NOT NULL)"
```

with the following code

```
#include "datainfo.h"
#define CREATE_TABLE \
    " CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS yourTable" \
    " (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL" \
    ", path1 TEXT NOT NULL" \
    ", path2 TEXT NOT NULL" \
    ", imageA BLOB NOT NULL" \
    ", imageB BLOB NOT NULL)"
```

Comment: Thank you very much Yoda! Next time an error check on the syntax of `SQL` would be more than necessary.